# result for print(5*2*3.14) is wrong in Python

Tags: python

[image]

version is 3.10.5 and I don't know what to try

Comment: I got the problem but can you help me solve it now? I'm not good at English that much either Python as well

Comment: that's because of how float works. Math is not broken, floats are just finite binary notations which doesn't translate 1 to 1 to decimal.